# How can I change the ivy defaults for diff?

Tags: ivy, diff

When I invoke `diff` I get two ivy prompts.
The first one defaults to the current buffer, the second often to some kind of backup.

It is quite awkward to navigate from the backup path to any useful location,
so I was wondering if I could change that.
Is it from ivy? Or from diff? Can I use advice here?

Ideally the second prompt would default to the path of the buffer in another open window,
or if there is none, default to the same location as the first.

*I am using Doom, if that matters.*

Comment: The default is determined by `diff`, not `ivy`; specifically the function `file-newest-backup`. FWIW, you can repeatedly type `M-n` (`next-history-element`) to see other default file suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but that function doesn't do anything useful for me.

Comment: You could advise or set the [interactive spec](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html) of `diff` to use your preferred default instead of `file-newest-backup`; or you could write a custom function with your preferred interactive spec that in turn calls `diff` non-interactively. You could also submit a feature request or patch upstream via `M-x report-emacs-bug` to make `diff`'s default prompt more customisable.

Comment: Actually, `M-n` has become a staple in my workflow now, thank you very much :)